# propensity to pay in healthcare Datasets

Tags: data-request, medical

I am searching for data-sets or data sources (free or paid) to do a propensity to pay model for healthcare industry. I found many solutions that offer complete solutions but whats interesting to me that they always include 3rd party data sources. I wanted to know where I can find such data, and where also can I ask.

Comment: Hi @Omar Baz, since it might be unclear to non-experts in this domain, can you give us some more details on what you expect the data to look like?  For example, what is the typical data generating context, what kind of outcomes and covariates are you interested in, is there a specific geographic or temporal range, etc.

Comment: I want data for example from a medical facility (hospitals/doctors) in USA that contains the medical bills for each patient and whether he paid or not this specific medical bill with features that describe this patient.

Comment: Seems like that might be hard to find in the public domain.  Take a look at the answers to these posts: [one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6568/7031), [two](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10301/7031).